# What is the URL for Chrome's Apps Page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

The Chrome desktop browser (on OS X, Linux, Windows) has an "Apps Page" to display installed Chrome apps.

It can be useful to know the exact URL of the built-in Chrome "Apps Page" so you can link to it, bookmark it etc. It is also difficult to discover this URL as it is not always displayed in the address field when you visit the page.

**What is the URL for this page?**

Answer (score 20):

The URL for the Google Chrome "Apps Page" is:

```
chrome://apps/
```

Comment: Easiest rep you've ever made

Comment: Doesn't work now on version 99.0.4844.94... `The webpage at chrome://apps/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`